# "500 Syntax error, command unrecognized" with FtpWebRequest in active mode (UsePassive = False) on Azure VM

Tags: c#, .net, azure, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I have a test C# console app that uses `FtpWebRequest` to transfer a file to a public FTP server.

The app **works from my Dev PC** with UsePassive set to False.  However, when I copy the app to an Azure VM it raises the following exception:

> The remote server returned an error: (500) Syntax error, command
>   unrecognized.

So in summary, these are the results when running the app locally and on Azure:

```
UsePassive  Local PC   Azure VM
----------  --------   --------
True        ok         ok
False       ok         ERROR!
```

Enabling tracing for `System.Net` shows the following (extract):

```
System.Net Information: 0 : [5716] FtpControlStream#60068066 - Created connection from 10.0.0.4:49706 to 90.130.70.73:21.
System.Net Information: 0 : [5716] Associating FtpWebRequest#45004109 with FtpControlStream#60068066
System.Net Information: 0 : [5716] FtpControlStream#60068066 - Received response [220 (vsFTPd 2.3.5)]
System.Net Information: 0 : [5716] FtpControlStream#60068066 - Sending command [USER anonymous]
System.Net Information: 0 : [5716] FtpControlStream#60068066 - Received response [331 Please specify the password.]
System.Net Information: 0 : [5716] FtpControlStream#60068066 - Sending command [PASS ********]
System.Net Information: 0 : [5716] FtpControlStream#60068066 - Received response [230 Login successful.]
System.Net Information: 0 : [5716] FtpControlStream#60068066 - Sending command [OPTS utf8 on]
System.Net Information: 0 : [5716] FtpControlStream#60068066 - Received response [200 Always in UTF8 mode.]
System.Net Information: 0 : [5716] FtpControlStream#60068066 - Sending command [PWD]
System.Net Information: 0 : [5716] FtpControlStream#60068066 - Received response [257 "/"]
System.Net Information: 0 : [5716] FtpControlStream#60068066 - Sending command [TYPE I]
System.Net Information: 0 : [5716] FtpControlStream#60068066 - Received response [200 Switching to Binary mode.]
System.Net Information: 0 : [5716] FtpControlStream#60068066 - Sending command [PORT 10,0,0,4,194,43]
System.Net Information: 0 : [5716] FtpControlStream#60068066 - Received response [500 Illegal PORT command.]
System.Net Information: 0 : [5716] FtpWebRequest#45004109::(Releasing FTP connection#60068066.)
System.Net Error: 0 : [5716] Exception in FtpWebRequest#45004109::GetRequestStream - The remote server returned an error: (500) Syntax error, command unrecognized..
   at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.SyncRequestCallback(Object obj)
```

Here is the source code to my app:

```
var fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("this is a test");

Console.Write("UsePassive? (y/n)");
var passive = Console.ReadKey();

var usePassive = passive.Key == ConsoleKey.Y;

var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://speedtest.tele2.net/upload/mytest.txt");
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("anonymous", "anonymous");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
request.UsePassive = usePassive;
request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

using (var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    requestStream.WriteAsync(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
}
using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Upload File Complete, status {response.StatusDescription}");
}
```

The Azure VM is not part of a network security group.  I've tried disabling the firewall on the VM but the app still raises the exception.

How can I resolve this?  It's a requirement that my app has `UsePassive` set to `False`.

Comment: Why do you use `UsePassive=False`? - Actually this most likely [the same problem you have with `ftp.exe`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51770347/850848). It's just that the `FtpWebRequest` has a bad habit of "translating" FTP error code to its own (quite often misleading) interpretation. In this case, it translated 500 to *"Syntax error, command unrecognized."*, hiding away original FTP server error message that was probably *"Illegal PORT command."*.

Comment: But while `ftp.exe` supports active mode only, so you have no other option. With `FtpWebRequest` you can (and should) use the passive mode, solving the problem.

Comment: The 3rd party FTP server that I'm trying to connect to does not support Passive.  I get the following error: The remote server returned an error: 227 Entering Passive Mode.  (The 3rd party FTP server is not the one shown in example code)

Comment: If the server did not support passive mode, it would never respond *"227 Entering Passive Mode"* - Looks like you have [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) - Instead of solving the issue with passive mode (which you should use), you ask a question about active mode (which you should not use).

Comment: I just set UsePassive = True & that's the error that is logged.

Comment: Sure, that what you already wrote in your previous comment. But it does not invalidate my response.

Comment: So the problem is with the server?

Comment: Unlikely, as you can connect from other machine. - I'm just saying that you should ask a question about the problem with the passive mode, rather than about the problem with the active mode. Unless you have a very good reason to use the active mode (what you do not seem to have).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177789/discussion-between-user1651370-and-martin-prikryl).

Answer (score 1):

```
PORT 10,0,0,4,194,43
500 Illegal PORT command.
```

10.0.0.4 is a private IP address. You cannot send a private IP address to FTP server, as it cannot connect back to it (hence 500 error). You have to use your public IP address. I do not know how to override a local IP address for `FtpWebRequest`. Checking .NET source code, it actually seems to me, that it's not even possible.

As I have already wrote you: Do not even try to use the active mode. It is complicated to setup from a network perspective. See my article on [Network configuration for FTP active and passive modes](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftp_modes).

So again, **use passive mode**. I'm aware that you also have problems with the passive mode. But they are more likely solvable than the problems with the active mode.

---

If you insist on the active mode, use FTP client library that supports specifying a local IP address.

For example with [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library):

```
// Set up session options
SessionOptions sessionOptions = new SessionOptions
{
    Protocol = Protocol.Ftp,
    HostName = "10.0.0.4",
    FtpMode = FtpMode.Active,
};

using (Session session = new Session())
{
    session.AddRawConfiguration(@"Interface\ExternalIpAddress", "your public IP address");

    // Connect
    session.Open(sessionOptions);

    // Upload
    session.PutFiles(@"C:\local\path\file.txt", "/upload/mytest.txt").Check();
}
```

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

You still have to open the VM firewall for all data connection ports.

---

While I didn't test it, it looks like that if local machine (VM) has only IPv6 IP address, `FtpWebRequest` would use `EPRT` command **without** an IP address, instead of `PORT` command with IP address. What would also solve your problem. You still have to open the VM firewall for all data connection ports.